# why is wordpress redirecting to home page after form submit?

Tags: forms, wordpress, form-submit

I am using 'get' method submit the form, but instead of form being submitted to the same page, it redirects to homepage.

`<form id="myform" name="myform" action="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>" method="get">`

Comment: Please show the form's generated HTML as well

Comment: It works completely fine while using 'post' instead of 'get'. So i am sure html structure is correct. It only happens when 'get' method  is used and i need to use get in this case.

Comment: Have you viewed the generated source markup and checked that the value of `action` is correct?  You could also try `<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>` and see if this works.